# Images append(jQuery) not clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

i saw some threads about this topic, but no one helps :(
I have the following problem, after my ajax i append some li's and img's.
I put a class for all my images and after that, my image containers are not clickable. i saw on a thread here that some call to use the jquery `live()` function, but it doesnt work for me and i tried on() also.

Example:

```
$('.CLASS').live('click',function(){
    alert("LETS ROCK");
});
```

Here my success Function (Ajax )

```
for( x in data.data)
              {
                   if( data.data[x].type == "image" )
              {
            $('.CLASS ul').append('<li><img class"insta_element" src="'+data.data[x].images.thumbnail.url+'"></li>');                       
                    }
                }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Try `$('.class').on('click', 'img', function(){...});` and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198)

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for years

Comment: ty guys for the answers :) i tried it later i go to bed now ^^